# Text Align on 2 Lines

Tags: css, text-alignment

I have four elements with text, some of which has text on two lines. I want to place the text in the center of the element, which I've done with text-align. However, the text that is on two lines I would like to be left-aligned with itself so it's flush to the left.

Like this:

First Line of text

Second line of text

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nj1pnnoj/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='nw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
          <span class='caption'>Night <br /> Life</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id='ne' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>News</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='sw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Food & Drink</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='se' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Events</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.bootply.com/assets/example/bg_blueplane.jpg');
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.bg {
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:50%
}
#nw {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last:left;
}
#ne {
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('news1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
#sw {
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    background-image: url('drinks1.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
}
#se {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlay {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}
.bg:hover .overlay {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    opacity: 1;
    height:100%;
}
.caption {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    color:white;
    z-index:100;
    font-size:24pt;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: font-size .4s ease-out 1s;
}
.bg:hover .caption {
    font-size:72px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `text-align: left` and `display: inline-block` to the inner `span` elements:

```
.overlay span{
    text-align:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nj1pnnoj/2/

Comment: Thanks. I also was able to do this by making a another class and using position:fixed; right:50%;